# How to Parse LocalStorage JSON object in Django View from Ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, django-templates

I am trying to submit **localstorage** data via a POST request using the below jquery ajax method. How should  I write my view so I can Parse my JSON object and get a hold of "product_id" to execute the below command in my Django view. Please see a copy of my view below.

Trying since one week, but I failed to fix the issue

Is there any better way of achieving this ?

My Ajax:

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
        var compare = localStorage.getItem("comparisionItems");
        var compareObj = JSON.parse(compare);
        
        var data_url = window.location.href;
        console.log(compare)
        console.log(compareObj)
        
       
          
          $.ajax({
            url: data_url,
            type: "POST",
            data: {'compare_id': compareObj },
            headers: { "X-CSRFToken": $.cookie("csrftoken") },
            success: function (result) {
                console.log("Success")
                
            },
        
            
        });
    });
```

and My Views:

```
def compare(request):
is_ajax = request.headers.get('X-Requested-With') == 'XMLHttpRequest'
if is_ajax and request.method == "POST":
    compare_id= request.POST.getlist('compare_id[itemIds]')
   
    product = get_object_or_404(Products, id=compare_id)
    context={ 'product':product}
   
   
    return render (request, './compare.html', context)
```

Actually my localStorage is on following format:

("comparisionItems"({ images: products, itemIds: itemIds }));

Can you please help me how can I pass itemIds to views and return item from views for the itemsIds?

Console log for console.log(compareObj)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/vtT9T.jpg

Comment: What is your Django version ? the .is_ajax() is deprecated since Django version 3.1: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.is_ajax

Comment: Django version is 3.2.7

Answer (score 0):

since `.is_ajax()` is deprecated you cant use that, but you can check if the request is an XMLHttpRequest like below.

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

def compare(request):
    is_ajax = request.headers.get('X-Requested-With') == 'XMLHttpRequest'
    if is_ajax and request.method == "POST":
        compare_id = request.POST.get('compare_id')
        product = get_object_or_404(Products, product_id=id)
        context={ 'product':product,}
        return render (request, './ecommerce/compare.html', context)
```

note; the get_object_or_404 is just a shortcut for:

```
try:
    product = Products.objects.get(product_id=id)
except:
    raise Http404
```

Comment: Thank you for the help, Actually my localStorage is on following format:

localStorage.setItem("comparisionItems", JSON.stringify({ images: products, itemIds: itemIds }));

Can you please help me how can I pass itemIds to views and return item from views for the itemsIds?

Comment: Your solution is not working, can you help with other possible solution please?

Comment: what exactly isn't working ? Did you get any error messages ?

Comment: I am getting this error :
string indices must be integers